# Start a wpf.exe application with a c# console app?

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I have a wpf application (.exe) on my desktop. I made a c# console application that have to start it. But I get a `FileNotFoundException`

This is what I have:

```
 var process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.FileName = "MyWpfAPp.exe";
 process.Start();
```

Did I forget something?

Comment: Yes, to put in the full path to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick for you if the file is on and always will be on your desktop

```
var fileLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
var fileName = "MyWpfAPp.exe";

var path = Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName );

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
process.Start();
```

Comment: my bad, try again

Comment: `GetFolderPath`already returns string `.ToString()` redundant. Also what is this `.Dump()`? Never seen it. @Bayern: This notwithstanding this code should work (without Dump()). Typo in your app name?

Comment: @LocEngineer thats from LinqPad, and was concepting the code in there. LinqPad uses Dump to show it to the screen

Comment: @Simon Price, it works half :P, no error's but the App wont start :/

Comment: @SimonPrice hmm no, if I double click it just starts..  I added a image

Comment: is that exe on the desktop or in a folder on the desktop?

Comment: @SimonPrice Its in a folder, but I used the right pad. The console app runs but the .exe wont start when I run it..